# JSP url-mapping to specific controller

Tags: java, jsp, jsf, web.xml, url-mapping

Im using jsp for web app and my requirments are as follow:

I need to navigate to **MyController** on each of the following urls:

```
http://localhost:8080/context/MyController/blah.jsf
http://localhost:8080/context/MyController/moreBlah.jsf
http://localhost:8080/context/MyController/andEvenMoreBlah.jsf
```

The url supposed to be `http://localhost:8080/context/MyController.jsf`

I need to do that without using custom servlet or filter.

Is there some way to do so with web.xml??

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you add below mapping pattern in web.xml for your MyController servlet then all three request you mentioned will be handled by MyController only.

```
<url-pattern>/context/MyController/*</url-pattern>
```

Comment: Not working, Im still getting apache error 404 as follow:                      type Status report

message /context/myController/blah.jsp

description The requested resource is not available.

Comment: Are you aware URLs are case sensitive?

Comment: Sure. Thats not the problem, the problem is that it look for proper .xhtml file for the url, when its not found its automaticly  look for proper .jsp file, when this not found the error is happend.

Comment: what i want to do is to parse the url, cut the "/blah" from it and then the proper .xhtml file will be found, but, do it without using filter